# Adobe Flash .sol location

Tags: files, flash, adobe

I've looked around the internet for a while and this forum/place and still can't find an answer. So, I decided to register and ask the question.

I'm looking for the location of .SOLs when you play flash games. Usually in Windows OSs they're located in the c:\users\documents & settings\username\appdata\shared objects\macromedia\CODE\here (or similar) but I've been looking around and can't find the location of the file.

The reason being is I want to move my flash game files from a Windows PC to my Ubuntu and play them. My only [temporary] solution is to get a Windows VM, but that's laggy as it's an old PC.

Any solutions or answers are very welcome ^^

Edit: Thanks i'll try the solutions soon.

Answer (score 4):

Try under `~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/CODE/here`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
locate .sol
```

Which will list all the ".sol" files on your system.